# Laravel -How to Update a form containing a file input type

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I have been trying to update a form that has file inputs. I want users to only change the files if they are not satisfied with the previously set file, else the previously set file will be updated in the database while the form is submitted. The data fetched from my database (i.e the previously saved file info) is $query->document->name which is meant to represent the name of the file

My form code looks like this:

```js
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="account_statement">{{$form->name}} :*</label>
    <input class="form-control" value="{{$query->document->name}}" id="{{$form->short_name}}" name="{{$form->short_name}}" type="file">
        
    </div>
</div>
```

My written code is however not getting the result I want done. The form is not even showing that a file has been set already.

Comment: Are you not using ajax for this?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, the browser does not let you set the value of an input file. You would have to use javascript to determine if the file exists.

Your html code would contain two displays, one showing the file if it exists, the other showing the input file. You then use javascript to determine when to show which display. Something like this:

```
  <span id="documentName">{{$form->document}}</span> <button id="removeFile">Remove</button>
  <input class="form-control d-none" id="document" name="document" type="file"/>
```

Javascript

```js
// I assume you are using bootstrap and hence jQuery
<script>
  $('button#removeFile').click(function(e) {
    if(@{{ form->name }})
      $('documentName').addClass('d-none')
      $('document').removeClass(d-none')
    }
  }
</script>
```